# How to use ajax to return a list of ViewComponents in .NET Core for pagination?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core webpage that displays a list of video thumbnails. On this page I have a "Load More" button that uses ajax to query and return a list of new thumbnails to append to the page.

I am familiar with the following method to request a **single** view component from my controller:

```
function getVideo() {
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: `api/videos`
}).done(function (response) {
    //response contains a video object
    //using .get() I can hit my server to return a view component for that specific video
    $.get(`/Video/LoadVideoViewComponent/${response.id}`, function (data) {
        //add the components to my html
        $('#video-list').prepend(data);
    });
})
}
```

Here is the controller to `LoadVideoViewComponent`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoadVideoViewComponent(int id)
{
    var video = await _db.Videos.FindAsync(id);

    return ViewComponent("Video", video);
}
```

Ok great, I've appended **a single video to my page**, but what if my api endpoint `api/videos` returns multiple videos. How would I return several `ViewComponents` and append them to my page? The only method I can think of is to loop over the `$.get()`, but that would make an absurd amount of server hits. Is there a way to return a **list** of view components using ajax for my pagination method? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make new Component returning all videos and loop on videos in Videos view.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoadVideosViewComponent()
{
    var videos = await _db.Videos;

    return ViewComponent("Videos", videos);
}
```

Now you can make a single call.

```
function getVideos() {
$.get(`/Video/LoadVideosViewComponent/`, function (data) {
        $('#video-list').prepend(data);
    });
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Agreed. One `ViewComponent` that handles output for 1 or more videos.